# How to bind multiple eventhandlers on WindowsPhone 8 using XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm about to make a control page that has several textblock. 
each textblock will be "linked" to another page,

here's my xaml part

```
.........<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="settingSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Tap="{Binding TapMethod, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SetTitle}" FontSize="43" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SetDescription}" FontSize="19" Margin="0 0 0 10" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>..........
```

when I try this code behind :

```
  .........public class SettingProperty
    {

        public string SetTitle{get; set;}
        public string SetDescription{get; set;}
        public string TapMethod{get; set;}
        public SettingProperty(string setTitle, string setDescription, string tapMethod)
        {
            SetTitle = setTitle;
            SetDescription = setDescription;
            TapMethod = tapMethod;
        }
    }

    List<SettingProperty> DataSetting()
    {
        List<SettingProperty> settingCollection = new List<SettingProperty>();
        settingCollection.Add(new SettingProperty("Saldo", "cek saldo", "saldo_Tap"));
        return settingCollection;
    }

    private void saldo_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/saldo.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }..........
```

I directly deployed them to my L520, I'm prety sure the culprit is the "Tap" binding on my stackpanel, when I omit it, the code works.
Did I miss something, or my whole method is just wrong?

Comment: Why is a string being bound to the Tap event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

our understanding of the "Tap" event is wrong.

You have two options here:

- Either you clearly specify a METHOD NAME (not a string) as a event handler for the Tap event. For example:

  Tap="MyControl_Tap"
  In this case you must have a MyControl_Tap method in your control's code behind
- OR, since you seem to be using the MVVM pattern, you have to create a ICommand, and then include your whole StackPanel in a Button, like this:

  ```
  ...<DataTemplate>
  <Button Command="{Binding MyCommandProperty}">
                      <StackPanel toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" >
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding SetTitle}" FontSize="43" />
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding SetDescription}" FontSize="19" Margin="0 0 0 10" />
                      </StackPanel>
  </Button>
  ```

  ...

Comment: thanks for your answer, i got your idea, 
but i end up using string from :  string selectedEvent = ((SettingProperty)((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext).TapMethod;